# How to use QueryAsync and ScanAsync in DynamoDB AWS C# SDk?

Tags: c#, .net, amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb

I'm trying to use the QueryAsync function of the AWS C# SDK, this is my code:

```
var request = new QueryRequest
{
    TableName = "happy-projects",
    KeyConditionExpression = "PK = :PK and SK = :SK",
    ExpressionAttributeValues = new Dictionary<string, AttributeValue> 
    {
        {":PK", new AttributeValue { S =  "ORG#prueba2" }},
        {":SK", new AttributeValue { S = "EMP#prueba2" }}
    }
};
    
var res = context.QueryAsync<DataModelSchema>(request).GetRemainingAsync().GetAwaiter().GetResult();
    
Console.WriteLine(res);
```

After the code is ran it showing to me this message :

> System.InvalidCastException: 'Unable to cast object of type 'Amazon.DynamoDBv2.Model.QueryRequest' to type 'System.String'.'

I'm currently using `.Net Core 3.1` and the `AWS` DynamoDB SDk.

I'm currently using .Net Core 3.1 and the AWS DynamoDB SDk.

This is my context declaration:

```
public static IAmazonDynamoDB client;
client = new AmazonDynamoDBClient(RegionEndpoint.USWest2);
DynamoDBContext context = new DynamoDBContext(client);
```

and this is my DataModelSchema class:

```
namespace DynamoDB
{
    [DynamoDBTable("happy-projects")]
    public class DataModelSchema
    {
        [DynamoDBHashKey]
        public string PK { get; set; }

        [DynamoDBRangeKey("SK")]
        public string SK { get; set; }

        [DynamoDBProperty("name")]
        public string name { get; set; }

        [DynamoDBProperty("email")]
        public string email { get; set; }

        [DynamoDBProperty("Data")]
        public string Data { get; set; }

        public override string ToString()
        {
            return string.Format("{0} - {1}", name, email);
        }
    }
}
```

This is the full error message:

```
System.InvalidCastException
  HResult=0x80004002
  Message=Unable to cast object of type 'Amazon.DynamoDBv2.Model.QueryRequest' to type 'System.String'.
  Source=AWSSDK.DynamoDBv2
  StackTrace:
   at Amazon.DynamoDBv2.Converter`1.TryTo(Object value, Primitive& p)
   at Amazon.DynamoDBv2.Converter.TryToEntry(Object value, DynamoDBEntry& entry)
   at Amazon.DynamoDBv2.Converter.ToEntry(Object value)
   at Amazon.DynamoDBv2.DynamoDBEntryConversion.ConvertToEntry(Type inputType, Object value)
   at Amazon.DynamoDBv2.DataModel.DynamoDBContext.ToDynamoDBEntry(SimplePropertyStorage propertyStorage, Object value, DynamoDBFlatConfig flatConfig, Boolean canReturnScalarInsteadOfList)
   at Amazon.DynamoDBv2.DataModel.DynamoDBContext.ToDynamoDBEntry(SimplePropertyStorage propertyStorage, Object value, DynamoDBFlatConfig flatConfig)
   at Amazon.DynamoDBv2.DataModel.DynamoDBContext.ValueToDynamoDBEntry(PropertyStorage propertyStorage, Object value, DynamoDBFlatConfig flatConfig)
   at Amazon.DynamoDBv2.DataModel.DynamoDBContext.ComposeQueryFilter(DynamoDBFlatConfig currentConfig, Object hashKeyValue, IEnumerable`1 conditions, ItemStorageConfig storageConfig, List`1& indexNames)
   at Amazon.DynamoDBv2.DataModel.DynamoDBContext.ConvertQueryByValue[T](Object hashKeyValue, IEnumerable`1 conditions, DynamoDBOperationConfig operationConfig, ItemStorageConfig storageConfig)
   at Amazon.DynamoDBv2.DataModel.DynamoDBContext.QueryAsync[T](Object hashKeyValue, DynamoDBOperationConfig operationConfig)
   at DynamoDB.DataModel.RunDataModel() in \DynamoDB\DynamoDB\DataModel.cs:line 80
   at DynamoDB.Program.Main(String[] args) in DynamoDB\DynamoDB\Program.cs:line 17
```

Comment: Try converting res to a string first. `JsonConvert.SerializeObject(res)`

Comment: @user15119845 thanks for your response, I have tried to do it, but the error is the same.

Comment: It would be helpful to add some more details to your code example.  What's the type of `context`?  What package is that coming from?  And what's the full stack trace for your execption.

If you're looking for a getting started guide for how to Query and Scan a DynamoDb table, you can try here: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/QueryAndScanMidLevelDotNet.html

If you want a full example, this might also be useful: https://github.com/ppittle/cdk-talk-2021/blob/main/CloudAutoGroup/Shared/FullQuoteRepository.cs#L42

Comment: @PhilipPittle thanks for responsing my question, I've added the context and the full error message.